# Are questions related to a particular type of music on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions related to a particular type of music on topic here?

For Example, I am an Indian music fan. I mostly listen to soundtracks from movies of [Bollywood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood) and [Tollywood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_cinema). I might ask or answer questions related to Indian music. Is this on topic here?

Comment: Why not???????? (Those question marks are for it to reach the minimum permissible length as a comment)

Comment: Just to clarify before posting any related questions

Comment: I recommend making this question more broad to include all types of music so we can close other questions as a duplicate later on

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sounds good. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Sri I can't due to our rep limitations, that's the reason why I commented :P

Comment: @ZachSaucier Oh so How do you want me to edit it?

Comment: @Sri You can click the "edit" button below the question tags to do so. I'd rename it to "Are questions related to particular types of music on topic here?" and update some of the body text to be more general

Comment: @ZachSaucier How is the question now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I foresee a great deal of crossover with [another SE site](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soundtrack).

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  Music is music.