# Do we need country tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

E.g., the OP of [this question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/are-questions-related-to-a-particular-type-of-music-on-topic-here) clearly intends to post questions about Indian music. I am pretty certain I have questions about Soviet or Russian music.

Should we introduce a per-country tag as a concept?

*(I'm not asking about tags for specific countries - if the "in concept" idea is approved, we can add them once specific country is covered by a threshold # of questions)*

Comment: Could you include (made up) example questions?

Comment: Genres are much more descriptive about what type of music a post is about then the country of origin. Some sub-genres will include country, but I don't think we'll want to make tags for every sub-genere as there are _way_ too many and there is too much overlap/debate on the finer definitions of them.

Comment: @unor - random example: what were the main musical influences on Aquarium (admittedly, a poor question as [Wiki addresses it directly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarium_%28band%29)). Or "which brands of Western musical instruments were accessible to rock bands in USSR legally in 1970s".

Comment: I agree with Dom.  Too many tags can get messy, if a country is vital to the answer then put it in the question.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I was going more for being able to filter ONLY for Indian (or ONLY USSR) music. Or vice versa, if too many Bollywood questions that someone has zero interest in, filter them out

Answer (score 1):

A lot of music could be said to be broadly international and possibly wouldn't benefit much from a country tag. I can't see a *big* win from tagging questions about Justin Bieber as 'canadian' or 'canada', for example.

However, as per DVK's comment above, I think there would be some value in allowing people to filter down to, say, Russian or Indian music (which might include questions needing more 'regional knowledge' to answer).

Just to address Dom's comment :

> Genres are much more descriptive about what type of music a post is about then the country of origin.

That's clearly a true statement, but I'm not sure that everyone comes to the site with the intention of focusing on a specific type of music. I'm interested in learning about Korean culture for example, and am therefore interested in seeing all questions about Korean music, regardless of actual musical style. I'm not actually Korean, but I imagine that if any real Koreans come here, they too might want to look at questions that would be likely to be in their area of expertise.

So - I would recommend a 'neutral' approach to country tags. I don't think there should be a frantic effort to go around adding country tags to every question, but I don't think people should go around removing them either if they have been added and seem appropriate.

Comment: In this case, why iwn't the genre enough? With [k-pop] you'll know it's Korean, with [flamenco] it's Spanish, with [fado] it's Portuguese etc... why being redundant ? Maybe the country in the title could be enough.

Comment: @Bebs 'flamenco' may tell you that a question is about Spanish music *when you are already looking at that question*, but it's less helpful when your use-case is that you want to filter questions to *find* Spanish-music-specific ones.  (Incidentally, that would mean that I was wrong to remove 'korean' from the questions I'd tagged 'k-pop'!). I think the real question is: how common is this use-case?

Comment: Putting meta-information like country in the title seems a bit messy given that we have tags for that purpose.

Comment: I really do have a problem with this as it sets a bad president for tagging. You've just tagged 4 separate questions with [tag:korean] which already have the tag [tag:k-pop] which will always need to be accompanied by the korean tag now for the tagging system to make sense.

Comment: @Dom I think in some of those cases I was re-adding a tag I'd already removed (and then decided that I'd done so erroneously). It may be that actually we don't want the k-pop tag - but as per my conversation with Bebs in chat, I thought we should work out the country issue first. So if you could respond to the more general points I've made in this post, that would be helpful.