# Is asking about genre oriented festivals on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I would like to learn about German retrowave/synthwave festivals but can't google up anything recent.
Is it on topic to ask this here?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer to [this Meta question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/are-questions-related-to-a-particular-type-of-music-on-topic-here?rq=1), I'd say it's on-topic to ask about festivals geared towards a specific genre.

Comment: As long as the question otherwise meets the site standards - no open ended list questions.